# Cannot connect to Openstack Instance via horizon, but SSH works?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, vnc, networking, openstack

I've got an OpenStack deployment running inside a VM for testing purposes. My setup is as follows: Host Ubuntu x64 with Virtualbox -> Guest Ubuntu x64 with OpenStack -> Ubuntu X64 Server Test Instances through Openstack.

I realize it is of no practical use, but as said, it is for testing purposes only. I successfully launched an instance, binding it to 11.1.0.3 and 172.16.1.1 (host is 172.16.0.1) and I can successfully ssh into it from either the host or the guest VM with `ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@11.1.0.3` (or `172.16.1.1`). Unfortunately, the NoVNC via Horizon does not work (Starting VNC handshake -> Failed to connect).

The relevant lines from my nova.conf are the following:

```
--novnc_enabled=true
--novncproxy_base_url=http://172.16.0.1:6080/vnc_auto.html
--vncserver_proxyclient_address=172.16.0.1
--vncserver_listen=172.16.0.1
```

So I'm not sure what's going wrong. The keypair that matches the .pem file I ssh with is of course coupled with the instance, and the instance is Active and Running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: `nova get-vnc-console [id] novnc` correctly supplies me with a link to vnc into the vm, but it also fails to connect.

**Edit 2**: To clarify: I have an active, running instance that successfully launched through the OpenStack dashboard. I can ping the instance, I can ssh into it (using `'ssh -i key.pem ip`), but I cannot access it through VNC (specifically novnc on the dashboard). Trying to access the VM through the URL nova supplies through get-vnc-console does not work either. What I wish to do is access this instance via VNC.

Comment: So is your question about VNC on openstack or VMz not being reachable.

Comment: Sorry if it was a little unclear: I added clarification as to what I meant. I wish to access the instance via VNC, but cannot as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your URL reference should be your public IP.

> novncproxy_base_url=http://:6080/vnc_auto.html
>
> xvpvncproxy_base_url=http://:6081/console

Try that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that slightly? In my nova.conf above, I have: `--novncproxy_base_url=http://172.16.0.1:6080/vnc_auto.html`, with 172.16.0.1 being the VM's (= the system running Openstack services) public IP address as far as it is concerned. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Put `--vncserver_listen=0.0.0.0` instated of `--vncserver_listen=172.16.0.1` in your configuration. Restart relevant services then try to access the instance via VNC.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the compute node you want to access from NoVNC

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5900:5950 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

If this is the right solution save it

```
iptables-save
```

Hope you can find the solution.
Regards Gerardo